# IIS Rewrite Rule - redirect specific HTTP page

Tags: windows, redirect, iis, rules

here is my rule:

```
<rule name="RedirectHttps04" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^some-url-here$" />
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/some-url-here" />
</rule>
```

With the above rule I would like to redirect a specific URL to https and keep all the other ones as they are.

So when user goes to:

```
www.example.com/some-url-here
http://example.com/some-url-here
http://www.example.com/some-url-here
```

I would like them to be redirected to:
https://www.example.com/some-url-here

But, after going through many versions and options available here - non of them worked, after reading multiple articles I don't see why the rule above doesn't work (doesn't redirect).
I'm using IIS 8.5.96

More info:
{HTTPS} parameter appears to be always "off"
{HTTP} is either "" for http or "off" for https, but even so the rule doesn't work

I have set to redirect to test.html?p={CACHE_URL} and both appears to take me to test.html?p=http://example.com

The only thing I have that works is a rule which appends parameter at the end if it's not appended, a very ugly hack but ensures user ends up on https :/